# Free street parking in Montreal

Tags: automobiles, montreal

I'm looking for free street parking in Montreal near to city center. I found [this website](http://www.statdemtl.qc.ca/en/parking/paid-on-street-parking.html) and there are 4 payment zones. So if I park on the selected street, will it be free of charge?

[image: Rue Saint-Christophe]

Comment: You could try Street View on that block and look for signs or parking meters...

Comment: Yeah, but signs on the streets could be change more often than street view is updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the the site, it is not free, at best it is 1$/hour at worse it is reserved for resident.

On the stationnement de Montreal site, When you zoom on the map:

"NOTE : les zones non colorées sont tarifées à 1 $ / h."

There are some free spots here and there, but hard to find.

have a look at [Parkopedia](https://en.parkopedia.ca/)

I used this zip code, H2L 3T9 to center around where you are looking for.
 (click on the "street" button at the bottom)

There doesn'T seem to be a lot of free space for the whole day.

I always suggest finding a paid parking garage spot as a plan B.

Answer (score 6):

Not completely. Most of the street is non-stopping. Part of it is not paid because it is reserved for those with a residence permit. There may be a few free spots in between but those are rather limited around the Montreal downtown area. There is also a moment, usually an hour or so, some days when parking is not allowed along the whole street, so you cannot park for free over extended periods.

Generally, Montreal parking is paid around the center of the city from 9 am-9 pm weekdays and 1-6 pm on weekends. This gives you free parking the *rest* of the time. A portion of what is left of the city center is reserved for residents, usually the whole day, but there are many areas where it is reserved for part of the day or night only. Unfortunately parking rules in Montreal are rather complicated and you may have up to 3 signs applying different rules to the same side of a street block.

Comment: I'm agree with that parking in Montreal is so complicated, especial when all informations on signs are in French language.

Comment: Just to be clear, in the case of that specific street: No part of it is paid hourly. It is either no parking, resident only or free. Although no-parking times apply to all spaces there. This is the case of most residential streets in that part of town. I used to work a few blocks from there and got pretty good at knowing which spots were available and when to give up and pay for parking under the building!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this blog post and built a map to find [free parking in Montreal](https://www.spotangels.com/montreal-parking). It is mainly downtown for now but the map can be edited by anybody a la Waze.

There is a free spot just nearby on rue Robin between St André et Labreque https://www.spotangels.com/#id=296811059&address=941%20Rue%20Robin%2C%20Montr%C3%A9al